# Login and Create Account HTML Forms in One Div

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have two forms that are specified in one div. One is for login and the other is for create account. The login form works well but the create account button gives the login error even though it is to call the create-account.php file.

Below we have the code.

the login  create / account forms

```
<?php
include('login.php'); // Includes Login Script

if(isset($_SESSION['login_user'])){
header("location: index.php");
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Login</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="main">
<div id="login">
<h2>Login Form</h2>
<form action="" method="post">
<label>UserName :</label>
<input id="name" name="username" placeholder="username" type="text">
<label>Password :</label>
<input id="password" name="password" placeholder="**********" type="password">
<input name="submit" type="submit" value=" Login ">

<span><?php echo $error; ?></span>
</form>

<form action="create-account.php" method="post" >
<input name="submit" type="submit" value=" Create User ">
</form>
</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

the login.php code is given below

```
<?php
include('config2.php');

session_start(); // Starting Session

$error=''; // Variable To Store Error Message

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
if (empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['password'])) {
$error = "Username or Password is invalid";
}
else
{
// Define $username and $password
$username=$_POST['username'];
$password=$_POST['password'];

// Create connection
$con = mysqli_connect($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password, $db_database , 3306);


// Check connection
    if(mysqli_connect_error()){
 die("Connection failed: ".$con->connect_error);
                             }

// To protect MySQL injection for Security purpose
$username = stripslashes($username);
$password = stripslashes($password);
//$username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
//$password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);


// Retrieve data from database

$sql="select * from admin where password='$password' AND user_name='$username'";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

$rows = mysqli_num_rows($result); 


echo sizeof($rows);

if($rows == 1) {
$_SESSION['login_user']=$username; // Initializing Session
header("location: profile.php"); // Redirecting To Other Page
} else {
$error = "Username or Password is invalid";
}

$con->close(); // Closing Connection
}
}

?>
```

The create-account.php file has no codes.
Any suggestion.

Comment: if you just need username & password for login and also to create account, you don't need separte file to create account, you can do it with if / else statement, just make sure both submit buttons have different name and on posting `if` login add login code and `else` create account code and set your header redirection or messages what ever

Comment: The problem is the name is same. Assign id to both buttons and bind event on that id

Comment: ok I just need to add an else statement to the first if and then change the header direction.

Comment: not necessary even with same button name it can be done like this `if(isset($_REQUEST['submit']) && $_REQUEST['submit']=="login") {put your login code here} else if if(isset($_REQUEST['submit']) && $_REQUEST['submit']=="register") { put your registration code here}`

Comment: Will the login and  register be the form id or button id , forgive my asking am new to php

Comment: @faisalabdulai if you wana do with jquery or javascript, then button `id` but if you wana do it with pure php then button `name=""`

Comment: @Shehary am using php so I tried it like this name="login" and name="registration" for the names but the forms do not post the data and buttons do not respond when clicked

Comment: Check your login form it doesnt has action file 'action="login.php"'